# Select Only First 3 Sub Divs In Nested Loop

Tags: css, css-selectors

This should be simple but I can't seem to target the first three specific divs within a nested div loop

```
<div class="content”>
     <div class=“thumbnail"></div>
     <div class="meta">
          <div class="author"></div>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="content”>
     <div class=“thumbnail"></div>
     <div class="meta">
          <div class="author"></div>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="content”>
     <div class=“thumbnail"></div>
     <div class="meta">
          <div class="author"></div>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="content”>
     <div class=“thumbnail"></div>
     <div class="meta">
          <div class="author"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

How do I target only the first three .meta divs? I've tried .content:nth-child(-n+3) .meta as well as .meta:nth-child(-n+3) but neither work.

Any help targetting the first three occurrences​ of the meta div in the loop? This is a Wordpress loop by the way and I want to selectively style the first three posts differently from the rest in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you want the first three metas from the first 3 contents....

```css
.content:nth-child(-n+3) .meta {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
     <div class="thumbnail"></div>
     <div class="meta">
          <div class="author">author</div>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
     <div class="thumbnail"></div>
     <div class="meta">
          <div class="author">author</div>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
     <div class="thumbnail"></div>
     <div class="meta">
          <div class="author">author</div>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
     <div class="thumbnail"></div>
     <div class="meta">
          <div class="author">author</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

also be aware of using always the same `"` !!! you have different ones in your example code.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have to reach for `.content` first and then select `.meta`:

```
.content:nth-of-type(-n+3) .meta {
  //your style
}
```